# Why isn't my InnerException making it to the client?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have the following code on the server:

```
if (actualRowCount > maxRows)
{
    throw new DomainException("OverMaxRowLimitException",
        new OverMaxRowLimitException(string.Format(MaxRowsMessage,
        actualRowCount, maxRows)));
}
```

This creates a new `DomainException` with the `InnerException` property set. I've verified that this is set in the debugger.

The custom exception is defined thus:

```
public class OverMaxRowLimitException : Exception
{
    public OverMaxRowLimitException(string message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public new string Message { get; set; }
}
```

This is supposed to return a sensible error message to the client so the user can be told there are too many rows. So in the load complete handler we'd like to have:

```
if (result.HasError)
{
    ShowError(result.Error.InnerException.Message);
}
```

Unfortunately, the `InnerException` property is `null`. So all we have to check is the text of the outer exception message which isn't being transferred to the client properly either.

It has been suggested that I need:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

in the web config file. I've tried this and it doesn't work.

It's also been suggested that I need:

```
[KnownType(typeof(OverMaxRowLimitException))]
```

on the data contract. Now unless I've put this in the wrong place, this also doesn't work.

I've also tried adding `[Serializable]` to the custom exception and replacing it with the general `Exception`. Neither of these worked either.

So, why is the `InnerException` property null. What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at this so question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717231/faultexception-and-custom-exception-wcf

Comment: I think you should employ FaultContracts.

Comment: Have you tried this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766527/exception-handling-in-ria-service

Comment: @Jehof - we are using a `DomainException`.

Comment: Have you tried to .share the OverMaxRotLimitException with your silverlight client project?

Comment: Do you override the method OnError of your DomainService to set property `Error` of the `DomainServiceErrorInfo`?

Comment: @Jehof - yes, I did share the exception and that didn't work either. Though I hadn't set the `[Serializable]` attribute at that point. No, we haven't overridden the `OnError` message.

Comment: Take a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightwcf/thread/95098d9f-95cf-42b0-be32-324ce434ec73 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378601/ria-services-and-faultcontract. I think it is not possible to pass custom exceptions to silverlight clients

Comment: @Jehof Good pointers. I never worked on silverlight before but i rather find this article interesting - http://mark.mymonster.nl/2011/02/10/make-use-of-wcf-faultcontracts-in-silverlight-clients/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should be using

`[FaultContract(typeof(OverMaxRowLimitException))]`

for your operation contract for this. And your `OverMaxRowLimitException` should be serializable.

Also in the usage, I suppose proper way to throw the exception is to use

`throw new FaultException<OverMaxRowLimitException>(yourException);`

Comment: The exception has the `[Serializable]` attribute set.

Comment: Yes, I have notice it in your question, Also I suppose you enabled ` <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />` in your config.

Comment: Yes we have got it set. But this wouldn't help in release.

Comment: Yes, that should be better turned off in production as it might send all the server exceptions to client. That's why there is FaultContract to send only the fault details required for the end user to see.

Comment: I'm looking into FaultContracts now